# Enable --hyperlink-source for "cabal install"

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

The command `cabal haddock` has very useful --hyperlink-source option.
I would like to have the source hyperlinked when building documentation with `cabal install`.

The ticket #517 seems to be just about it: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/517

However, perhaps it is possible to set this flag via ~/.cabal/config file?

If not, how can I get working cabal-install build with the patch from #517 without installing Cabal-1.9, which is currently mandatory (due to one patch from December)?

Comment: What is the problem with installing Cabal-0.9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you cannot get the equivalent of the `--hyperlink-source` option when using the "all in one" `cabal install` command. The ticket you cite is exactly about this issue.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: The upcoming Cabal 1.20 [has this fixed](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/1707): it adds a `haddock` section in `~/.cabal/config` where you can say `hyperlink-source: True`.

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked:

```
cabal update
cabal install haddock
```

Edit config file `~/.cabal/config`

Enable `Documentation: True` (removing "-- " at the beginning of the line is fine)

---

**Cabal Library:**

```
cd ...someNicePlace...    

cabal unpack Cabal
```

Edit file `Distribution/Simple/Setup.hs`, therein find `defaultHaddockFlags = ...`

I switched some of them from False to True:

```
... 
haddockHoogle       = Flag True,
...
haddockHtml         = Flag True,
...
haddockExecutables  = Flag True,
...
haddockHscolour     = Flag True,
...
```

having **haddockHscolour** the only important one (don't have to change the others if not want to).

Install updated Cabal Library:

```
sudo cabal install --global
```

---

**cabal-install (cabal shell command)**

To get the updated Cabal Libary working within cabal shell command, I reinstalled cabal-install also:

```
cd ...someNicePlace...    

cabal unpack cabal-install

sudo cabal install --global
```

---

Since then the shell command `cabal --version` says to me:

```
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2 
using version 1.16.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

And, as wanted, any new cabal install is now installing full haddock html documentation with source codes hyperlinked as default.

Answer (score 3):

Ticket #517 is about passing haddock options via cabal, like if you have special needs like building a hoogle database or usa a different CSS

Most users will be happy with standard haddock and hyperlinked sources though, which is possible with Cabal-1.8. Ticket #517 is if you have bigger needs.

Simply calling `cabal haddock --hyperlink-source` should do the trick.

If you want this as the default, you can edit `~/.cabal/config` as you mentioned.

Comment: Does that default get used when Haddock doc gets built as part of an invocation of "cabal install some-package"? I think that is what the OP is after - and what doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't want to ever call 'cabal haddock' myself. I want to be able to build and install programs with 'cabal install' and have source hyperlinked in the process.

Comment: Oh,  I see. I'm unaware of such a solution.