# Where does cabal put the hyperlinked source?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472630/enable-hyperlink-source-for-cabal-install#comment35437211_3930939), you can cause cabal-install to also hyperlink the source of the package you are installing. Where does it put theses sources? Do I need to enable any other options or packages to acquire them?

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `~/.cabal/config` file for the `install-dirs` stanza:

```
install-dirs user
  prefix: ...
  -- bindir: $prefix/bin
  libdir: $prefix/$compiler-$arch/lib
  libsubdir: $pkgid
  -- libexecdir: $prefix/libexec
  -- datadir: $prefix/share
  datasubdir: $compiler-$arch/$pkgid
  docdir: $prefix/$compiler-$arch/lib/$pkgid/doc
```

The `docdir` setting is what you're interested in.