# Why isn't Cabal hyperlinking my sources?

Tags: haskell, hyperlink, cabal, haddock

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.2.0
using version 1.22.2.0 of the Cabal library 


$ cabal install --haddock-hyperlink-source gloss-juicy
Warning: /home/theking/.cabal/config: Unrecognized field hyperlink-source on
line 91
```

I do have `hyperlink-source: True` on in my config. I added the flag just to be redundant. When I look for the docs, it is all colorized and everything, but the source code isn't linkified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of `haddock` is cabal calling?

Comment: @user5402 I have 2.16.1 installed. I don't know which it is using.

Comment: I don't think that version is new enough. Does that haddock understand the `--hyperlinked-source` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully we're talking about the `haddock` command line option `--hyperlinked-source` (note hyperlink**ed**).

Version 2.16.1 does not support the `--hyperlinked-source` option.

Version 2.16.2 does support the `--hyperlinked-source` option.

You might have to build 2.16.2 from the git repo:

https://github.com/haskell/haddock

Comment: Oh, so it isn't officially out yet then?

Comment: Well - it's not on Hackage. It's confusing, because there is also a cabal haddock  option called `--hyperlink-source` (note: no **ed**) See this old SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2472630/866915